# WPF call to library not working (thread problem)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke

I have a third party library that i'm using to produce some kind of message.

My code works in a console app, but when I call it from a WPF .xaml.cs class, it does nothing!

In debug, I get into the Produce(Message) fonction, and after that, nothing! I don't catch any exception and I never get to the next line.

The exact same code works perflecty in a console app.

Help :(

```
        try
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Wait;
            _producer.Produce(message);
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little class I wrote for this purpose:

```
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    private Cursor _previousCursor;

    public WaitCursor()
    {
        _previousCursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Mouse.OverrideCursor = _previousCursor);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Use it like this:

```
using (var cursor = new WaitCursor())
{
    // Your long-running code here
}
```

Comment: Very nice! You could consider switching from `class` to `struct` as the type of `WaitCursor`, to avoid the minuscule overhead of one allocation (micro-optimization, I know!).

Answer (score -2):

I've fixed it by englobing my code in a method and doing :

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ProduceMessage();
        });
```

Comment: Note that `Task.Factory.StartNew` should simply be `Task.Run`, and that it should be awaited: `await Task.Run(() => ProduceMessage());`

Comment: This just papers over the problem by pushing it onto another thread.